# How to create a direct call between 2 objects

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-2.0

I use C# 2.0 & WinForm for my application.
My form has 2 user controls with names: UserControl1 & UserControl2.

UserControl1 has a event CriteriaChanged:

```
public event CriteriaChangedHandler CriteriaChanged;
public delegate void CriteriaChangedHandler(object sender, CriteriaChangedArg e);
```

UserControl2 has a function:

```
public void Do(CriteriaChangedArg e){...}
```

I must use my form like as an intermediate object:

```
userControl1.CriteriaChanged += userControl1_CriteriaChanged;

private void userControl1_CriteriaChanged(object sender, CriteriaChangedArg e)
{
userControl2.Do(e);
}
```

How to create a direct call without myForm, when userControl1 raise a event CriteriaChanged, userControl1 will be called with Do() function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats wrong with your current method? Seems pretty standard.

If you change the signature UserControl2

```
public void Do(object sender, CriteriaChangedArg e)
```

you could do this...

```
userControl1.CriteriaChanged += userControl2.Do;
```